# Private aggregate initialization

Tags: c++, aggregate-initialization

Is it possible to define as `private` the **aggregate initialization** for an **aggregate** class? I would like that the class can only be aggregate-initialized by its own static private members.

Example:

```
struct Size
{
    const unsigned int width;
    const unsigned int height;

    static const Size big;
    static const Size small;

private:

    Size( ) = default;

    // something to declare the aggregare initialization as private
};

const Size Size::big = { 480, 240 };
const Size Size::small = { 210, 170 };
```

Comment: What do you mean by "define as private the aggregate initialization"?

Comment: How does guidance like "make the constructor `private`" not help you?

Comment: For what reason do you need this struct to be an aggregate?

Comment: @MikeKinghan no reason in particular, just asking if it is possible

Comment: No it's not. That "something" could only be a user-defined constructor,
and an aggregate by definition hasn't got any of those.

Comment: @MikeKinghan may I suggest that you write the comment as an answer so it's easier to see?